# Angular(MSAL)においてAzure ADの認証画面に遷移させる前に任意の処理を行う方法は？

Tags: typescript, azure, oauth, angular

下記ドキュメントを参照し、Azure ADとAngular(MSAL)使用した際の認証を検証しています。

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/entra/identity-platform/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code

当方の環境では上記ドキュメントの「Sign in using redirects」を使用し、
「Implement Angular Guard」で保護したルートにアクセスした際、
認証が行われるようにしています。

保護したルートにアクセスされた際、以下のような動きを実現したいのですが、
良い方法はありませんでしょうか。

１）Azure ADの認証画面に遷移する前に任意の処理を実行する
　２-A）「1）」の結果に問題が無ければAzure ADの認証画面に遷移させる
　２-B）「1）」の結果に問題が有ればAzure ADの認証画面に遷移させることなく
　　　　任意の画面(例：エラー画面)に遷移させる